# How does the interactive "Interactions" pane in DrJava work?

Tags: java, ide

The Java IDE "DrJava" has an interactions pane which allows you to type in single lines of code and have it interpreted on the go (sort of like python IDLE). How is this possible given that Java code has to be compiled? It also keeps track of variables and even classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might actually use a compiler - either the one included in JDK or for example  "Eclipse Compiler for Java". The only other option is to parse the source code to AST and execute it - which is close to creating new programming language. 
Looking at FAQ: http://www.drjava.org/faq.shtml#interactions-differences it seems like it is actually custom JVM language and it only looks very similar to Java.